# Full height window on load and scroll when window resizes

Tags: javascript

I have an idea for a layout. When users first load a page. The content will be display full window height. But when users resize the window, it will add a vertical scroll bar to view the full window height.

To put into another, it is like I want to keep the full height window when users resize the window.

Example, initially the window full height is 1600px, and then when users use a mouse to resize the window to 1000px for example, I want the content still 1600px and a scroll bar is added to help users view the content.

And if users open the window initially at let's say the smaller screen 800px height. I want it first make full height but then when users resize the content will fit the resize window.

Am I confused about my idea but is it possible to do so?

Comment: Well thats exactly what a browser does. If you have a `<div style="height: 150%"></div>` the browser will automatically add the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean zoom when you say resize and mouse. You can use

```
window.resize = function() {
 //will be called whenever the window changes size. I.E zooming in or changing the window size manually
}
```

To pick up that behaviour, but the best approach I believe would be the place the content you wish to have this property into a div wrapper. As that way you can set the size manually.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

**Let's do it by steps:**
are you using any framework ?, Frameworks generally use the window's resizing base, the percentage of the window used, so it will adapt whenever the user decreases or enlarges the screen, if you want the static screen when resizing, change the css attributes of your framework, or create your layout with pixel or hexadecimal from scratch. To create an adaptive window on the first access and then leave it static, first you have to put your highest value DOM element (html, or window) in css, and the other elements you leave in pixel values, if you need , also use the ["position: fixed"](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) attribute.